# How to align bullet points in an unordered list in the center using inline CSS

Tags: html, css

Trying to align the bullet points in an unordered list in the centre of the page using inline CSS but it is not working.

I have tried using 'text-align:center;' and 'list-style-position: inside;'

```html
<div style="text-align:center; list-style-position: inside;">
  <ul>
    <li> blah </li>
    <li> blah rujrij32itjo2jtij32ijti42jtij24tji4jtij2 b32ru h13ru3r31tt</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The text and the bullet points go to the center but the bullet points do not align underneath each other.

I'm trying to code the following project from freecodecamp: https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/zNqgVx

Comment: you probably need to give a width to the div and center it from margin:auto; you can comment answers aside editing your question to clarify it. I'll delete my answer since you did not mind it ;) ... Welcome on SO

Answer (score 0):

I believe the result you're after is achieved by changing the list's display to inline-block and then setting the text-align to left

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li> blah </li>
    <li> blah fdsf ds fds fdsf s</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How about if there are multiple lines of text within an <li> and you want to position the bullet point at the horizontal center of the lines?